# Powershell script to delete all list items found in a specific list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

I have multiple lists with 100k+ items. I've created views with old/retired data that I need to delete. I've named the views "tobedeleted". Is it possible to run a powershell script to delete only the list items found in the specific "tobedeleted" view?

This is for SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Comment: If you plan to run this script on a regular basis you should consider Not to use the view to define those items, as somebody else might change the view. I learned that the hard way

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$site = get-spsite http://yourServer/sites/yourSite
$web = $site.RootWeb  # change to select your site
$list = $web.Lists["Test"]
$view = $list.Views["View1"]
$items = $list.GetItems($view)
for ($i=$items.count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--) { $item = $items[$i]; $item.Delete(); }
```

Notes:

- This will only delete the number of items normally displayed in the view. I.e. 30 by default.
- You may need to run this in batches of 5000 or less.
- Note that the loop counts down, not up.
- To move the items to the recycle bin, call .Recycle() instead of .Delete().
- To add a "count down" so you can see how far along it is, change the "for" loop to add a "write-host":

> ```
> for ($i=$items.count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
> { 
>    $item = $items[$i]; 
>    $item.Delete(); 
>    Write-host -NoNewLine "$i        `r"
> }
> ```